# How to add view model to existing phtml and block

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, layout, xml, phtml

Is there any possibility to add ViewModel to the existing block and PHTMl file? I'm trying to add ViewModel to the file below.

```
sales_email_order_renderers
```

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder" name="sales.email.order.renderers.default" as="default" template="Test_Module::email/items/order/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Even though its late to answer your question, it may help someone. You can add viewModel like below arguments syntax.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder" name="sales.email.order.renderers.default" as="default" template="Test_Module::email/items/order/default.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Test\Module\ViewModel\Sales\Block\ViewModelClass</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the XML files will be merged in the end, so we can directly use the block name in the **referenceBlock** tag and change the template and add the view model  for additional functionalities. Find the below sample code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
      label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers.default" template="Test_Module::email/items/order/default.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Test\Module\ViewModel\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```